# spring kafka integration creating consumers dynamically

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am using Spring-Integration-Kafka and following is the sample for creating consumers dynamically to receive and print messages in the console.
Consumer class:

```
public class Consumer1 {
private static final String CONFIG = "kafkaInboundMDCAdapterParserTests-context.xml";
static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;

public static void main(final String args[]) {
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG, Consumer1.class);
    ctx.start();
    addConsumer("test19", "default8");

    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG, Consumer1.class);
    ctx.start();
    addConsumer("test19", "default10");

}

public static void addConsumer(String topicId, String groupId) {

    MessageChannel inputChannel = ctx.getBean("inputFromKafka", MessageChannel.class);

    ServiceActivatingHandler serviceActivator = new ServiceActivatingHandler(new MessageReceiver(), "processMessage");
    ((SubscribableChannel) inputChannel).subscribe(serviceActivator);

    KafkaConsumerContext<String, String> kafkaConsumerContext = ctx.getBean("consumerContext", KafkaConsumerContext.class);
    try {
        TopicFilterConfiguration topicFilterConfiguration = new TopicFilterConfiguration(topicId, 1, false);

        ConsumerMetadata<String,String> consumerMetadata = new ConsumerMetadata<String, String>();
        consumerMetadata.setGroupId(groupId);
        consumerMetadata.setTopicFilterConfiguration(topicFilterConfiguration);
        consumerMetadata.setConsumerTimeout("1000");
        consumerMetadata.setKeyDecoder(new AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaDecoder<String>(java.lang.String.class));
        consumerMetadata.setValueDecoder(new AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaDecoder<String>(java.lang.String.class));


        ZookeeperConnect zkConnect = ctx.getBean("zookeeperConnect", ZookeeperConnect.class);

        ConsumerConfigFactoryBean<String, String> consumer = new ConsumerConfigFactoryBean<String, String>(consumerMetadata,
                zkConnect);

        ConsumerConnectionProvider consumerConnectionProvider = new ConsumerConnectionProvider(consumer.getObject());
        MessageLeftOverTracker<String,String> messageLeftOverTracker = new MessageLeftOverTracker<String, String>();
        ConsumerConfiguration<String, String> consumerConfiguration = new ConsumerConfiguration<String, String>(consumerMetadata, consumerConnectionProvider, messageLeftOverTracker);

        kafkaConsumerContext.getConsumerConfigurations().put(groupId, consumerConfiguration);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

inbound config file:

```
<int:channel id="inputFromKafka"/>

<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect" zk-connect="localhost:2181"
        zk-connection-timeout="6000"
        zk-session-timeout="6000"
        zk-sync-time="2000"/>

<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter"
        kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
        auto-startup="false"
        channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"/>
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="kafkaReflectionDecoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaDecoder">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="java.lang.String"/>
</bean>

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext"
        consumer-timeout="1000"
        zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
    <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="default1"
                value-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder"
                key-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder"
                max-messages="5000">
            <int-kafka:topic id="mdc1" streams="1"/>
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
    </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>
```

When i send any message to topic "test19", configured ServiceActivator "processMessage" method displayed two messages as configured two customers but the question here is i need to load inbound config file for each customer before adding to consumer context.. otherwise i am getting only one message in my console.. Is it correct way or do i need to change anything here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you are trying to do but what you do have has problems.

By starting the context before subscribing your consumer you will likely have problems (Dispatcher has no subscriber on `inputFromKafka` during the short time between the start and subscribing).

Why are you programmatically creating the service activator rather than declaring it in the context?

It would be better to configure everything in the context (you can pass in properties such as `groupId` to the context via properties in the environment and using a property placeholder configurer.

Comment: Hello Gary, for me as requirement, I am trying to reduce as many as configurations in context and all i want is how to create consumers dynamically and distribute service activator messages to all consumers..